# Relational Database implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, database-design

Not sure what the best implementation of this is. I've got two different types of property that I want to track faults for. I'd like to be able to show the faults on the specific property's show page, and then view all faults on the faults index page.

Would it be better to have multiple faults tables relating to each property, or one faults table that each property links to? I'm concerned about having numerous multiple blank id attributes in the faults table if they are all put together. But if theyre split out, Im concerned about displaying them in the view. Im implementing this with rails.

One faults table

```
Cars                   Trucks                Faults
-----------            ----------           -----------
car_id                 truck_id              fault_id
attribute_1            attribute_1           car_id
                                             truck_id
                                             fault description
```

Two faults table (one per property)

```
Cars                   Trucks                car_Faults              truck_faults
-----------            ----------           -----------              -----------------
car_id                 truck_id              car_fault_id            truck_fault_id
attribute_1            attribute_1           car_id                  truck_id  
                                             fault description       fault description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either polymorphic associations with the models you have now, or single table inheritance to combine cars and trucks into a single class.

---

**Polymorphic association** looks like this:

```
Cars                   Trucks                Faults
-----------            ----------           -----------
id                     id                    id
attribute_1            attribute_1           faultable_id
                                             faultable_type
                                             fault description
```

You must add `faultable_id` (int) and `faultible_type` (string) columns to `Fault`. Models will look like this:

```
def Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :faults, :as => :faultable
end

def Truck < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :faults, :as => :faultable
end

def Fault < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :faultable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

allows you to do this:

```
@car.fault
# => returns car's fault

@fault.faultible
# => returns car or truck
```

---

**Single Table Inheritance (STI)** looks like this:

```
Vehicle                Faults
-----------            ---------- 
id                     id   
type                   vehicle_id
attribute_1            fault description
```

This is a bit tricky to understand, but `Car` and `Truck` will both inherit faults from the `Vehicle` superclass. This allows you to have cars and trucks associated with faults while using only one database table (*single table* inheritance).

Cars and trucks will be stored as a vehicle record, and will share common attributes. This is ideal for models that have nearly identical attributes, such as "color" or "make." Keep in mind that unused attributes (car attributes in a truck object) will be nil. If you're dealing with many non-interchangeable attributes (and therefore many nils), better use polymorphic associations instead.

Models:

```
def Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :faults
end

def Car < Vehicle
end

def Truck < Vehicle
end

def Fault < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

With this you can do:

```
@truck.fault
# => returns truck's fault

@fault.vehicle
# => returns either a Car or Truck object, depending on the type
```

There are some caveats with using STI:

- You must instantiate a subclass (Car or Truck); *never* instantiate the superclass (ie. `Vehicle.new`). Do not touch the `type` attribute of `Vehicle`. Rails handles it automatically.
- There are no collection class methods, so something like `Truck.faults` (faults of all trucks) will not work.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to play with it, but it looks like the polymorphic would work. I'm assuming you can have associations to more than 2 models by adding :as => faultable to all tables that need the association correct?  The tables above are a simplified representation of the actual models Im using

Comment: Correct. You can have as many models as you need in the polymorphic association, provided they all use the `:as => :faultable` interface.

Comment: Could I have you check this design implementation and see if it makes sense/works? I'm trying to make sure I've got this set up properly from the start instead of building off a poor design and running into problems accessing the data down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to show all faults together and also be able to show the faults for each property I would think a solution like this might be what you are looking for

```
Vehicles                Faults                      Types
-----------            -----------                 ---------
vehicle_id             fault_id                    vehicle_type
vehicle_type(FK)       vehicle_id(FK)                  
attribute_1            vehicle_type(FK)
                       fault_description
```

And then have an entry in `Types`, one for `Car`, and one for `Truck`


Edit: Upon further thought I realized that the `vehicle_type` in `Faults` is unnecessary because to get `Car` faults you could use:

```
SELECT fault_id AS F FROM Faults WHERE F.vehicle_id IN
  SELECT vehicle_id FROM Vehicles AS V WHERE V.vehicle_type IN
    SELECT vehicle_type FROM Types WHERE vehicle_type = 'Car'
```